# Settings to optimize 2.4ghz frequency on ASUS RT-AC87R for long range (120ft) reception

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an ASUS RT-AC87R that I'm using for long range (120 ft) reception. I'm wondering what settings I should adjust from the default settings for optimal 2.4ghz reception from 120 feet away. I have the 5ghz frequency disabled.

Update: It's in the downtown area of a small city. As of right now there are 10 other networks in range of my computer. We're sending the signal directly across the street because our building was only wired for DSL.

Here are the current settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this on a farm with no other WiFi networks nearby, or in a city with 50-100 Wifi networks in range?

Comment: It's in the downtown area of a small city. As of right now there are 10 other networks in range of my computer. We're sending the signal directly across the street because our building was only wired for DSL :(

Comment: So, you have your router in one building, and several PCs that connect to it in another, correct?

Comment: @Peter Correct!

Answer (score 1):

What you need are directional antennas between access points in *both* locations. You don't need more power. You do need to make sure you have minimal signal interference. Directional antennas are designed for this exact scenario. It's best if you put them outside, most models are made for that. Point them directly at each other.

Here's some examples from TP-Link:

http://www.tplink.ca/en/products/biz-list-5067.html

Answer (score 0):

With your setup, you can't do a lot with the settings, other than selecting an unused channel. See [Which Wifi Channel should I use?](https://superuser.com/questions/628840/which-wifi-channel-should-i-use) for advice on channel selection - it boils down to trying them all and seeing which works best. It's all dependent on interference. Getting a free channel will boost signal quality more than any other setting (other than Tx power).
I'd also set the Wireless Mode to N, assuming all your devices support N.

You'd get best reception by placing the router in your own office, in bridge mode, and installing a second router in the office across the street. Place them close to the outside wall in a room with no mirrors and without a lot of steel. Do not place them in such a way that a window is between them. Window glass can be extremely bad for WiFi, much worse than walls, depending on the exact type of glass.

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you so much. Where should we place the more powerful router (ASUS RT-AC87R)? I'll probably use a decent N-router in the other spot.

Comment: How are we suppose to know?  We know absolutely nothing about your building.

Comment: For the communication between the 2 routers it doesn't really matter in which office each of the devices is. For the communication between the 2-10 devices in your office and their closest router, it does. So I'd put the stronger device in your office. And for the other device I'd recommend going at least for one with dual antennas and wireless N support - you can find used devices like that for less than 20$. Getting triple antennas is even better, because that allows the device to boost directional signal strength (beamforming). For best throughput, use a router with directional 5GHz ac.